# Google compute engine - allowing access to a single server

Tags: google-compute-engine

I got multiple servers hosted on google compute engine, couldn't find a way to allow a contractor access to a single server, I have a budget authorized for a specific project and can't open a new project for that.

Adding a new team member seem to allow view / write / full access to all servers in the project.

Is there any way to allow access to just one server (or a subset of them) without opening a new project?

**Solution:** took @vgt advice and done the following:

on the remote machine generated a new key using:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

appended new public key file `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` content to `.ssh/authorized_keys` and pulled the file itself to local machine

now I can ssh the box using:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o  StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
-i <copied .ssh/id_rsa.pub> -o LogLevel=QUIET -A  -p 22 <username>@<ipaddress>
```

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Comment: @MarcB tried to post on serverfault, no google-compute-engine tag there

Comment: @MarcB also, thanks for explaining downvote, I wouldn't mind moving this question there if you have enough reputation to open a tag there, would you?

Comment: I didn't downvote, and nope. don't have much rep anywhere else but here.

Comment: who are those ppl that downvote and run away anyway? this is simply rude IMO

Comment: once they gain access to one instance, would they not be able to ssh to other instances through the instance that have access to?

Comment: @DXM I ended up taking another route, I guess you could restrict ssh other boxes by putting these box on another network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can administer access [using ssh without gcutil](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances?hl=en#standardssh) .